# How to count number of lines from HTML out in PHP

Tags: php, html

How can I count the number of 
 tags in HTML with PHP? I have a website which shows all of the bans on my game server, I want to count the number of bans that have been done, I see the only way to do this being counting the number of 
 tags, since the HTML output is all on one line. At the moment I have:

```
$content = file_get_contents('**WEBSITE OF BAN LIST HERE**')
```

The HTML output looks like this but **much much** longer:

```
hillel123 banned on 13/March/2014 with reason : None<br>xmrbrhoom banned on 13/March/2014 with reason : None by [name of banner]<br>InfinityJoris banned on 13/March/2014 with reason : None by [Name of banner]<br>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You could figure out how many bans there are by counting the occurrences of `<br>`? As long as the html is in that form..

```
echo substr_count($html, '<br>'); // How many new lines there are?
```

Answer (score 1):

You can count tags using this code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($HTML);
$allElements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('*');
echo $allElements->length;
```

Instead of (*) you can put any tags you want and you'll get number of those tags.

Answer (score 0):

The easyest way i can think of is that you make an array and then count it.
Since you have all that in one string you can easely do that :)

```
<?php
$content = file_get_contents('**WEBSITE OF BAN LIST HERE**');
$banns = explode('<br>', $content);
echo count($banns);
?>
```

Comment: Who downvotes this and doesn't give a reason... it works perfectly

Answer (score -1):

I think you want to use `file` [instead](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file.php) of file_get_contents. Then use the count() function to get the resulting array's length.

Comment: This could be a comment

Comment: That wouldn't work because they aren't actual line breaks, but `<br>` tags instead.

Comment: I think it's an answer.