# Replace all title attributes in an html document

Tags: php, dom, replace, html-parsing

I have html code in a variable. For example `$html` equals:

```
<div title="Cool stuff" alt="Cool stuff"><a title="another stuff">......</a></div>
```

I need to replace content of all title attributes `title="Cool stuff"` and `title="anot stuff"` and so on with `title="$newTitle"`.

Is there any non-regex way to do this?

And if I have to use regex is there a better(performance-wise) and/or more elegant solution than what I came up with?

```
$html = '...'
$newTitle = 'My new title';

$matches = [];
preg_match_all(
    '/title=(\"|\')([^\"\']{1,})(\"|\')/',
    $html,
    $matches
);
$attributeTitleValues = $matches[2];

foreach ($attributeTitleValues as $title)
{
    $html = str_replace("title='{$title}'", "title='{$newTitle}'", $html);
    $html = str_replace("title=\"{$title}\"", "title=\"{$newTitle}\"", $html);
}
```

Comment: You should make use of `SimpleXMLElement()` to convert the html into an object so that you can XPath over the nodes which have `title="whatever"`. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/65206705/2191572 to get started.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Ah, I didn't see the banner "There are disputes about this answer’s content ...". I've just seen that answer so many times when questions about Regex and HTML are asked 

Comment: To get all nodes with a title then this could be used `//*[@title]`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus thank you. That seems like the kind of solution I was looking for.

Comment: I can not accept this as correct answer so I will accept the other one(which was later) to close this up. But thank you again,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely don't use regex -- it is a dirty rabbit hole.
<sub>...the hole is dirty, not the rabbit :)</sub>

I prefer to use DomDocument and Xpath to directly target all `title` attributes of all element in your html document.

- `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` flags are in place to prevent your output being garnished with `<doctype>` and `<html>` tags.
- `//` in the XPath expression says: go to any depth in search of matches

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/3ZAQq))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<div title="Cool stuff" alt="Cool stuff"><a title="another stuff">......</a></div>
HTML;
$newTitle = 'My new title';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($html, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
foreach ($xpath->query('//@title') as $attr) {
    $attr->value = $newTitle;
}
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Output:

```
<div title="My new title" alt="Cool stuff"><a title="My new title">......</a></div>
```