# Regex with quotes

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I'm working on a project and I have a problem with regex, I want to test some html attributes and it works, but when I have a quotes inside this does not work.

[image]

When I add the quote I have this result.

[image]

So I hope you can help me. (I check in javascript)

```regex
/([-\$@\w\d\i]+)="([-. =\:;()'\$@\w\d\i]*)"/gim
```

Comment: The question is not clear, what do you expect it to match?

Comment: I want to match the first html attribute like the others

Comment: Well, it is not that difficult to deduce the pattern that should work, but you could explain the pattern requirements verbally. Something like `/([^\s=]+)="([^"\\]*(?:\\[\w\W][^"\\]*)*)"/g` should work.

Comment: You're using Javascript. Turn the string into a DOM Object and XPath it...

Comment: Like so https://stackoverflow.com/a/65206705/2191572

Comment: No I can't in my case, I don't have access to the DOM.

Comment: Maybe I can simulate the DOM, I'll do some tests later.

Comment: If you have a web browser, the ability to create a `.html` file, and open it in the web browser then you absolutely have access to the DOM.

Comment: In fact, if you do that then open the console in Chrome and use `$x()` to execute XPaths directly without the need for writing JS code.

Comment: My application is not used in a browser, I use Node to launch my script.

Comment: Please try `/([^\s=]+)="([^"\\]*(?:\\[\w\W][^"\\]*)*)"/g`. Does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```js
/([^\s=]+)="([^"\\]*(?:\\[\w\W][^"\\]*)*)"/g
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/7iKyGA/1). *Details*:

- `([^\s=]+)` - Group 1:
- `="` - a `="` text
- `([^"\\]*(?:\\[\w\W][^"\\]*)*)` - Group 2: any zero or more chars other than `"` and `\` and then zero or more repetitions of any escape sequence followed with any zero or more chars other than `"` and `\`
- `"` - a `"` char.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const regex = /([^\s=]+)="([^"\\]*(?:\\[\w\W][^"\\]*)*)"/g;
const str = 'title="Bonjour - \\"(le monde))\\"" style="color: red;" charset="utf-8" src="monImage.png" alt=""\ntes-t6=""';
let m, results={};
while ((m = regex.exec(str))) {
  results[m[1]]=m[2];
}
console.log(results);
```